# How to check what filter is applied

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I am developing exporting data in xpdl format. There are 2 options - version 2.1 and 2.2. I am using SaveFileDialog, but how can I distinguish between those 2 options?

```
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "xpdl 2.1|*.xpdl|xpdl 2.2|*.xpdl";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //how can I check, which format is selected?
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get or set selected filter for dialogs by checking [FilterIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filterindex) property. And as stated in msdn:

> The index value of the first filter entry is 1.

So for your task it would be:

```
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "xpdl 2.1|*.xpdl|xpdl 2.2|*.xpdl";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            switch (dlg.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    //selected xpdl 2.1
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //selected xpdl 2.2
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the Filter list. Then look at the FilterIndex.

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "xpdl 2.1|*.xpdl|xpdl 2.2|*.xpdl";
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] filterstring = saveFilaDialog.Filter.Split('|');
    MessageBox.Show(filterstring[(saveFilaDialog.FilterIndex - 1) * 2]);
}
```

Comment: Great answer sarathi...  I have over 30 filters so it would be a pain to have to do a case statement.